# Site.com Error for system administrator

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I am trying to edit site.com site in my org, Through i am system administrator it gives me access level error shown below:

'you do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary.'

Any suggestion??

Comment: Thanks for replys...!I have sorted the issue. In 'Site Configuration' we have to add the users and role for site.com. I have added the user with publisher role which allowing user to edit the site. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the security tips from https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5598/permission-problem-in-sales-forece and http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Force-com-Sites-Site-com/page-is-showing-insufficient-privilege/td-p/233797

If you're sure the security of the Site is fine - try to debug the site https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1149/how-can-i-get-a-debug-log-for-the-sites-guest-user-public-profile (because you might be getting an Apex error that's not being displayed on your VF page).

Did the site used to work or is it new? If it's new I'm betting on permissions (first 2 links), Guest User profile should be examined if he has access to the objects you're using...

Last but not least: there's a bug they've fixed 5 days ago: http://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000RivgAAC Maybe you need to use this workaround, maybe you simply can clone the site and it'll work fine...

Answer (score 0):

you have to check your profile, and i guess that there is someone who have created the profile for you and delegate you to be an administrator, if this is not your problem, you have to go to your personnal informations and click edit and you may find a checkbox which concerns "Site Publisher" you have to check it to be able to create and publish your site :)